# Split array in multiple arrays populate by order in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, split, sub-array

Array input:

```
$input_array = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e','f','g','h');
```

Desired output (4 arrays for example):

```
Array(
    'a',
    'e'
)

Array(
    'b',
    'f'
)

Array(
    'c',
    'g'
)

Array(
    'd',
    'h'
)
```

As you can see, **it's different output** than [array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-chunk.php). I want to fill in order the different arrays, one by one, when reach the last array go back to the first array and repeat until no more values.

I've tried so many possibilities but can't find the good one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate your values and fill array using modulo :

```
$input_array = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e','f','g','h');
$arrs = [];
$key = 0;
foreach ($input_array as $val) {
    $arrs[$key++ % 4][] = $val;
}

// $arrs contains what you want.

// Then you could extract them in separate arrays.
list($a1, $a2, $a3, $a4) = $arrs;
var_dump($a1, $a2, $a3, $a4);
```

Outputs :

```
array(2) {
  [0]=> string(1) "a"
  [1]=> string(1) "e"
}
array(2) {
  [0]=> string(1) "b"
  [1]=> string(1) "f"
}
array(2) {
  [0]=> string(1) "c"
  [1]=> string(1) "g"
}
array(2) {
  [0]=> string(1) "d"
  [1]=> string(1) "h"
}
```

Comment: I was going to suggest this too. I think it's simpler to use `foreach ($input_array as $key => $val)` rather than defining your own `$key`, but the way you've done it does account for unexpected keys.

Comment: @Don'tPanic You're right! Thanks for this interesting comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'];

for($i = 0, $res = []; $i < $l = count($a); $res[$i % 4] = [$a[($i + 4) % $l], $a[$i]], $i++);

print_r($res);
```

Comment: Code should be accompanied with a written explanation on how it fixes the issue in the OP.

Answer (score 1):

One-liners aren't necessarily good for readability, and the fact that this needs explanation means it isn't a good answer for code that needs to be maintained, but

```
$result = array_map(null, ...array_chunk($input_array, count($input_array) / 2));
```

The first part chunks the input array, not using 2 - which would give an array with 2 columns of data - but to give 2 rows of data, so the initial input would be converted to

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "a"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "b"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "c"
    [3]=>
    string(1) "d"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "e"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "f"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "g"
    [3]=>
    string(1) "h"
  }
}
```

The `...` operator in PHP passes an array of arguments too a function as though they are individual arguments, so effectively is passing the two rows from the array chunk as separate array arguments.

Calling `array_map()` with a `null` callback performs a "**transpose**" of the array arguments, as described for *Example #4* in the [PHP Docs for the function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php), which converts the 2x4 array in the example into a 4x2 array, giving

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "a"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "e"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "b"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "f"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "c"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "g"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "d"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "h"
  }
}
```

Comment: This is cool! Do you know of a way to keep it from adding nulls to the end of the result sub-arrays if it doesn't divide evenly? I was working on something similar but kept running into the same problem.

Comment: No, it will always pad with nulls to ensure consistent size; effectively you're treating it as a matrix, which has to be balanced, so PHP balances it by padding with nulls if necessary

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the index, incrementing by the number of output arrays you want. Then use an inner loop to get the individual elements.

```
$len = count($input_array);
$output_array = [[], [], [], []];
$stride = count($output_array);
for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i += $stride) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < $stride && $i + $j < $len; $j++) {
        $output_array[$j][] = $input_array[$i + $j];
    }
}
```